# Docker remote interpreter not showing up in newest PhpStorm

Tags: docker, phpstorm

PhpStorm 2018.2.3

I try to use xdebug with PhpStorm

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN pecl install -o -f redis
RUN pecl install -o -f xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable redis
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install locales-all -y
```

[image]

But the option for Docker as remote PHP never shows up.

I'm even connected to Docker over TCP from PhpStorm

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you check your enabled plugins? I believe it has to be "PHP Docker" plugin and you may have it in disabled state.

Comment: @LazyOne I didn't notice it wasn't enabled... thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please ensure that your **PHP Docker** plugin is enabled.

That plugin is responsible for adding Docker support in PHP Interpreters section.

Comment: I will not post this as a new question in this one, but PhpStorm does not seem to recognize the PHP interpreter located at `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: What does it say then? It should give some error message or alike. Check `idea.log` for possible hints if you do not see a way to see error details there (`Help | Show Log in XXX`)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/F0729nA the apache container is `FROM php:7.0-apache`

Comment: I will not be able to help with resolving this (I have very limited Docker experience). I may only say: 1) check `idea.log` for possible hints 2) check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=docker%20%23%7BPHP%20Interpreters%7D 3) post another question on [PhpStorm forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm) or here on StackOverflow.